# inserting list values into different rows while keeping the latest values for the other columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a data like this that has been stored in a file:

```
name    last_name     class
b        bc           ['1','2','3']
```

Now that I want to insert it into a table in MySql, I want the output look like this: (id is an auto increment field)

```
id       name    last_name     class
1        b        bc           1
2        b        bc           2
3        b        bc           3
```

So far, I was able to come up with this code, but it stores the whole list in a cell:

```
result=('C://heli.csv') 
count=0
db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "****", "myblog", local_infile=True,use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE dru FIELDS TERMINATED by '$' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (keyword,indication,name,dr_id,synonyms) SET id = NULL" % (result,))
db.commit()
count += 1
db.close()
print(count)
```

Is it even possible to separate out the values of a list like the one I am interested in?

actual data looks like this:
`coronary syndrome$for treatment $bivalirudin$['db00006', 'btd00076', 'expt03302', 'biod00076', 'db02351']$['bivalirudina', 'bivalirudinum', 'hirulog'`]

Comment: what is the structure of the data? is it a dataframe?

Comment: @mad_ a CSV file.

Comment: Then how it got converted to a list for column class? can you post the relevant conversion or how csv looks like?

Comment: @mad_  have included some data!

Comment: How are you reading this data in python?

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently in MySQL.
This is definitly not the best solution, but it will get you there.

If you can get your raw data into a MySQL table, you can use SubString to separate out each class, and insert into a new table.

E.g

```
select
   name,
   last_name,
   Substring_index(Substring_index(class, ',', 1), ',', -1) as class
from data;
```

will produce-

```
name    last_name     class
b        bc           1
```

Full code here-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c40a01/1

Comment: thanks. But, I have more than 1000 records. @jwood74

Comment: Does the number of records impact things? My select statement will grab the first 'class' of every record. Then a second select statement will grab the second class (you could union these together)